# Swift: Schedule a local notification for a specific time on weekdays

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, localnotification

Hi I am trying to schedule a local notification to fire at 9:00am on weekdays (mon - fri) and cant seem to find any documentation on how to do this. Here is my code so far:

```
@IBAction func scheduleLocal(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings() else { return
    }
    if settings.types == .None {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Cant Schedule", message: "No Permission", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = NSDate()
    notification.alertBody = "Come Exercise"
    notification.alertAction = "Exercise Time"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.userInfo = ["customField1": "w00t"]
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

Comment: I've felt firedate blank as I didnt know what to put into it.

Comment: You will need to schedule 5 notifications that repeat every week

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I add the dates and times on the notifications into it though?

Comment: As in, how would I set one of them up to repeat each week at 9:00 am as an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is my class example you can use it as you want , i also  support Arabic language by translate Arabic number to English .

```
//
//  notification.swift
//  NSFetchController Pro
//
//  Created by Mr.Geeker on 08/02/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 X2coder. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class notification {


    func createNotification(#hour:String, day:String, msgBody:String)->Bool
    {
        if(self.checkifNotificationOnOrOff())

        {



            //println("\(araToString(hour))")

            var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
            var convertedTime:String = ""

            var testDate:NSDate = NSDate()

            var timeFormat:NSString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(testDate)

            // Get the range of date (AM OR PM )
            var amRange:NSRange = timeFormat.rangeOfString(dateFormatter.AMSymbol)
            var pmRange:NSRange = timeFormat.rangeOfString(dateFormatter.PMSymbol)

            var is24h:Bool = (amRange.location == NSNotFound && pmRange.location == NSNotFound)
            if is24h {

                araToString(hour)

            }else{

                var dateFormatter2:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

                var hourDate:NSDate = dateFormatter2.dateFromString(hour)!

                var pmAmDateString:NSString = dateFormatter2.stringFromDate(hourDate)

                convertedTime = pmAmDateString
                println(convertedTime)

            }


            var hourAndMiOnly:NSArray = convertedTime.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
            var onlyHour:Int = 0
            var onlyMinuts:Int = 0

            for var i:Int = 0; i < 2; i++ {

                for  thimes in hourAndMiOnly
                {
                    if i == 0
                    {
                        onlyMinuts = thimes.integerValue

                    }
                    if i == 1 {
                        // we should add -1 before the class
                        onlyHour = (thimes.integerValue)
                        if onlyHour < 1
                        {
                            onlyHour = 00
                        }
                        break
                    }

                }
            }


            let DaysDic = [0:"None",1:"Sunday",2 :"Monday",3 :"Tuesday",4 :"Wednesday",5 :"Thursday",6 :"Friday",7 :"Saturday"]

            var ConvertDayToInt:Int?{

                for (key,value) in DaysDic
                {
                    if value == day
                    {
                        return key
                    }

                }
                return nil
            }

            //println("Hour is \(onlyHour) And Minut \(onlyMinuts) AND Day \(ConvertDayToInt)")

            let date = NSDate()
            var userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?

            var createCalender:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
            var dateComponenet:NSDateComponents = createCalender.components(NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.WeekCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
            dateComponenet.weekday = ConvertDayToInt!
            dateComponenet.hour = onlyHour
            dateComponenet.minute = onlyMinuts


            var fireDateToRun:NSDate = createCalender.dateFromComponents(dateComponenet)!

            var notificationClass:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
            notificationClass.alertBody = msgBody
            notificationClass.fireDate  = fireDateToRun
            notificationClass.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            notificationClass.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekCalendarUnit
            notificationClass.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
            notificationClass.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications = [notificationClass]


        }else{

            // call protocol function not support notification
        }

        return true
    }



    func araToString(numericString:String)->NSString
    {
        var nsMutString:NSMutableString = NSMutableString(string: numericString)
        let ArabicString:NSString = "١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩:"
        let EnglishString:NSString = "123456789:"

        for ( var i:Int = 0 ;   i < ArabicString.length ;  i++)
        {

            var a:NSString = ArabicString.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(i, 1))

            var w:NSString = EnglishString.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(i, 1))

            nsMutString.replaceOccurrencesOfString(a, withString: w, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range:NSMakeRange(0, nsMutString.length))


        }

        return nsMutString

    }


    func deleteAll(){

        let appnoti = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        let delArray = appnoti.scheduledLocalNotifications
        if delArray.count > 0
        {
            appnoti.cancelAllLocalNotifications()

        }

    }

    func checkifNotificationOnOrOff()->Bool
    {

        let systemVer:String = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion

        var finalFloat:Float = NSString(string: systemVer).floatValue

        if finalFloat < 8 {

            return false

        }else{

            return true
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Could you explain how this works/ what it does?

Comment: Hello , as you have seen in my class , createNotification(#hour:String, day:String, msgBody:String) this function to create a local notification by setting day in string and hour  as string and the notification text , 

This function araToString will convert the numbers from arabic to english 

in case you want to delete all notification just call deleteAll()

this function checkifNotificationOnOrOff is to check if notification is registered  or not , good practise  if you call it in first view or app delegate 

This is all about the class , I'm trying to help you as i know .